# Mass readings about husbandly conduct

Tags: marriage, mass

At Mass this weekend, we heard part of [Proverbs 31](http://usccb.org/bible/readings/111311.cfm) which is nice and all.  But my wife always complains that, "they always talk about how wives should act, they should say something about how husbands should act for once."

Are there any Mass readings during the 3 year cycle (or even the 2 year weekday cycle) that talk about how men should act.  I can't think of any other than "Husbands love your wives".

Comment: According to [Ephesians 5:25](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%205:20-30&version=NIV), the entire life of Christ could be interpreted as instructions for how husbands ought to behave. I have no idea how often any priests (or other congregational leaders/teachers) connect these dots when teaching. :)  (NOTE: I realize the entire life of Christ can apply to the lives of anyone, husband, wife, or unmarried. So it may not be a very interesting observation anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, the only thing is, I don't think that ever made its way into the lectionary, the beginning of Ephesians 5 is but, other Christians are probably more at liberty to use the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that [21st Sunday of the Year [B Cycle]](http://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/1998USL-OrdinaryB.htm) has at least part of what you are looking for, as Ephesians 5:21-32 has this from the KJV:

> ```
>  21Submitting yourselves one to another in the fear of God.
>
>  22Wives, submit yourselves unto your own husbands, as unto the Lord.
>
>  23For the husband is the head of the wife, even as Christ is the head of the church: and he is the saviour of the body.
>
>  24Therefore as the church is subject unto Christ, so let the wives be to their own husbands in every thing.
>
>  25Husbands, love your wives, even as Christ also loved the church, and gave himself for it;
>
>  26That he might sanctify and cleanse it with the washing of water by the word,
>
>  27That he might present it to himself a glorious church, not having spot, or wrinkle, or any such thing; but that it should be holy and without blemish.
>
>  28So ought men to love their wives as their own bodies. He that loveth his wife loveth himself.
>
>  29For no man ever yet hated his own flesh; but nourisheth and cherisheth it, even as the Lord the church:
>
>  30For we are members of his body, of his flesh, and of his bones.
>
>  31For this cause shall a man leave his father and mother, and shall be joined unto his wife, and they two shall be one flesh.
>
>  32This is a great mystery: but I speak concerning Christ and the church.
> ```

For the rest you can look through http://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/1998USL-OrdinaryA.htm and http://catholic-resources.org/Lectionary/1998USL-OrdinaryC.htm but these links don't include the readings from the daily mass, which may have some of the verses mentioned that talk about husbands.

Answer (score 0):

The Bible tell husbands that they should try to understand, try is the key word I think, so seems like this is keep her happy. It also says to do the hard and manly things for your wife because she is not as strong, which isn't always the case these days. Respect your wife is in there as well, seems pretty important. The Bible also tells you to do your husbandly duty and do it well. Last passage I found says he should provide for his family.

> "A man should try to understand what his wife needs, rather than being bitter toward her. He will not expect her to do heavy work since she is not as strong. And he will respect her as being of equal spiritual value with himself."

1 Peter 3:7 (NIV)

> "A husband also shows love by expressing affection and fulfilling the wife's sexual needs."

1 Corinthians 7:3-5 (NIV)

> "As the head of the family, a man should provide, not just for himself, but for his whole household."

1 Timothy 5:8 (NIV)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE ... please note that your participation is valuble and I'd love to see you stick around. I do need to mention that SE sites in general have rules about answers needing to directly relate to the questions, and on this site we've been working out what that means for having a diversity of Christian traditions as on-topic material. Basically we've decided that answers need to stick to the tradition being asked about. In this case the OP Peter has asked specifically about the Roman Catholic Lectionary and their specific liturgy of readings for mass.

Comment: Would you like to edit this answer to cover the content of the mass readings and whether any of them have content about husbands? If so please use the _edit_ link under your question.

Comment: please also make sure that when referencing the Bible, you cite which version you are utilizing! It's important to be able to follow-up in the future. Welcome to Christianity.SE, @Michael

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty important to specify the bible mentioned. A. Because in the context of the Catholic Mass in English in North America, the New American Bible would be used and B. Because 1 Cor 7:3-5 says in the NAB "The husband should fulfill his duty toward his wife, and likewise the wife toward her husband." So, even if this reading was read at Mass, which I don't believe it is in a cursory check of the lectionary, the likelyhood that it would be read in that context is pretty slim (but that's kind of unimportant). Nevertheless +1 for good Bible readings concerning husbandly conduct.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know there were so many rules. I was trying to help him find some verses on how a husband should act, feel free to remove this answer.

Comment: Most of my Bible quotes I get out of my NIV Bible, sorry for not posting that I am new to the site.

Comment: @MichaelR.Bailey I used the website mentioned [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66394/42721) to search for the verses in lectionary: 1 Peter 3:1-9 - Commune holy man and women, **wedding**; 1 Cor 7:3-5 - not read; 1 Tim 5:3-10 - Commune holy man and women, St. Hemma of Gurk (June 27)