# How to know when a particular verse of the Bible have been or will be part of the Liturgy of the Word? (Catholic)

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, liturgical-calendar

Is there a way to know (perhaps through an online database) when a particular verse of the Bible have been or will be read in Mass (if ever)? It could be under any rite (ordinary, extraordinary, Maronite, etc).

There are plenty of websites where you can check the particular readings of a given day (e.g. [here](http://www.acatholic.org/calendar-of-the-catholic-daily-mass-readings/) and [here](https://www.catholicgallery.org/mass-reading/daily-mass-readings-2019/)), but the format in which these are presented are not easy for searching, or they cover a short period. But clearly, these websites are being sourced from somewhere so there information, in principle, is out there.

The ideal resource would be one where you would input a verse, and obtain in return **exact dates** when that verse has been read or will be read.

PS: why would this be useful? Well, say you have a blog of biblical commentary and have reflections of a particular verse. You might want to publish the text when it coincides with the particular day it is read in Mass.

Comment: If you do this with your blog: Do you plan to write programs yourself?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Hi Martin. I'm not sure I understand the question. But if it's not already done, it seems to be something quite doable. Get lectures for every possible date into file (xml?), split joint verses into individual ones, and add search mode to website. It's something I would definitely love to do if time allows.

Comment: There are various rules used to find out which week in the year circle or holiday a certain day is. And somewhere there must be the rules which text is read on what holiday. Your program would for example calculate that a certain day is the Monday of the 19th week in the year circle. Then you look up the rules which text is read on the Monday of the 19th week. And doing so you find out which text is read on the certain day.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Sounds logical. As you say, "somewhere" these rules must be. Maybe they have not been electronically codified in an algorithm yet. Someone is perhaps doing it manually. The Vatican? hehe Maybe [this one](http://www.cultodivino.va) but the site seems to be badly maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The German Liturgic Institute has a [website](https://dli.institute/wp/praxis/schriftstellenverzeichnis-fuer-die-lesungen-der-messe/) with an index of all pericopes printed in one of the eight volumes of the German lectionary (ordinary rite). It has sites for each biblical book with the pericopes, the day when it is read and volume with site where it is printed (e.g. Num "11,4b-15; Mo 18. Wo. JK I; VI 3"). Everything is in German, but I think you can deal with it.

When the found liturgical day will be next time in the real world, you have to look up by yourself. There are also pericopes that are only read at special occasion (e.g. Num  3,5-9 at the consecration of a deacon).

Answer (score 4):

[Divinum Officium](http://divinumofficium.com/) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/DivinumOfficium/divinum-officium)), written in Perl, can do this. It contains [data files for the Mass](https://github.com/DivinumOfficium/divinum-officium-website/tree/master/web/www/missa) in several languages. Bible verses begin with a "!" (e.g., "!Num 17:8"), so you can easily search those files for verses. Divinum Officium [generates a liturgical calendar](http://divinumofficium.com/cgi-bin/horas/kalendar.pl), too.

Comment: Interesting, though it doesn't seem to include the 1969 calendar?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to link the datafiles to dates. The other answer, albeit in German, and only for the ordinary rite, does have what I need in a straightforward fashion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi there. Do you know how to search for a given psalm in the **Divine Office** files? Say you want to find when (liturgical day and Hour) psalm 80 is read (like today, Lauds). Which files would you look for? I can't quite get the structure of the files. (although it seems Matt is right; 69 calendar not included so might not show today as a result).

Comment: @luchonacho That sounds like a good feature you could suggest (by [submitting an "issue" / feature request here](https://github.com/DivinumOfficium/divinum-officium/issues/new)) that the developers implement.